# Basic Expectation and Variance properties, need clarification

Tags: probability, expectation, variance

I would like to understand what am I doing:

So for example, to find $\mathbb E[f(x)]$ I compute $\int x f(x) $

To compute $Var [f(x)]$ I compute $\int x^2 f(x) $, where does the $x^2$ come from?

When $X \sim N(0,5)$ I need $\mathbb E[X]= \int \sqrt 5 Z \times exp(-z^2/2) dz $

**My questions:**

1) For a random variable $X$, why don't I need to multiply by x just like in the first example? Why is it simply the integral of $X$ and it's probability distribution function, which in this case is just the standard pdf?

2) In the first example, does it mean that $x$ is the pdf?

3) How can one calculate variance using pdf? Let's say find the variance of $Y=e^{kX}$

Comment: *So, for example, to find $\Bbb E[f(x)]$, I compute $\int x f(x)$:* this is false.

Comment: Also, any computation should include the probability distribution of $x$ somehow

Comment: You can write 
$$
\Bbb E[f(x)] = \int f(x)\,P(x)\,dx = \int f(x)\,dP
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I see, what about variance? is the statement $Var[x]=\int x^2 f(x)$ true?

Comment: *That* statement is true if $f(x)$ is the pdf of $x$. Note, this is different from $Var[f(x)]$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom   I see, so if $X \sim N(0,5)$ I can find the variance by $Var(X)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int X^2 \times exp(-z^2/2) dz=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int ({\sqrt 5 Z})^2 \times exp(-z^2/2) dz$?

Comment: You have the right basic idea.  In particular, it's
$$
Var(X) = \frac 1{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int x^2 \exp[-(x/5)^2/2]\,dx
$$
This is a special case, however, since $\Bbb E[X] = 0$.  In general, $Var[X] = \Bbb E[X^2] - (\Bbb E[X])^2$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you very much